# TListview that scrolls horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: android, ios, listview, delphi, firemonkey

Can anyone give me a few pointers to do this?
Instead of the `TListview` that scrolls up/down, I would like the same kind of layout to be scrolled horizontally.

I can't seem to find a component but I have seen plenty of apps on App Store with this capability.

It must be able to support both Text and Photos as elements and support Live Binding to a database table as well.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand: a `TListView` can scroll horizontally, especially when having i.e. 50 columns.

Comment: Take a look at `THorzScrollBox` and populate it with `TMemo`s for text and `TImage`s for photos.

Comment: @AmigoJack Check the tags on this post. Peter is using FMX

Comment: I added a simple picture to show what I mean.